# Copy one cell to blank cells in a column, if another column has data

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, fill

I am rather new at this but eager to learn :)

Unfortunately I have been struggling below below problem for the last few days.

I need to copy the value of a single cell (J2), to column A from cell A3 to the last needed depending on the last row with data in column B (this will be dynamic) but this should be true only where the cells are blank. In the attached example I need for J2 to be pasted in column A lines 11 to 15.

I have tried various methods but I cannot seem to combine copying a single value (not a range) only for blank cells in column A depending on whether there are data in column B.

Any ideas?

Thanks mates!

I have tried below code but it is not working.

```
Sub copyLC()

Range("I2").Copy Range("A3:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Range("B3:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(3).Row).Copy Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(3)(2)

Dim lastRow1 As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim r As Long

lastRow1 = Sheets("equip_hlp").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("equip_hlp").Range("J3:J" & lastRow1).Copy

lastRow2 = Sheets("equip_hlp").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("equip_hlp").Range("I" & lastRow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long
For i = 3 To lastRow Step 1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" And Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(2, "J").Value

Range("B3:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(3).Row).Copy Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(3)(2)

Dim lastRow1 As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim r As Long

lastRow1 = Sheets("equip_hlp").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("equip_hlp").Range("K3:K" & lastRow1).Copy

lastRow2 = Sheets("equip_hlp").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("equip_hlp").Range("I" & lastRow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long
For i = 3 To lastRow Step 1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" And Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(2, "J").Value


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to loop from rows 3 to lastRow for a single column, and where a cell is blank, you paste a value?

The below mock-up assumes you can actually find the last row (e.g., you do not have a blank last row in column B)

```
dim lastRow as long
lastRow = cells(rows.count, 2).end(xlup).row
dim i as long
for i = 3 to lastRow Step 1
    if cells(i,1).value = "" and cells(i,2).value <> "" then cells(i,1).value = cells(2,"J").value
next i
```

Hopefully this is a good starting place for you... dynamically finding the last row in based on column B (2).

I added a check in the `If-statement` for Column B to have data, but may not be necessary if you're working with a contiguous data set, hence the last Row using B.

Comment: Cyril this worked like a charm! You are absolutely fantastic, thank you! I am having a problem combining this with a couple of other macros in the same module though.. the thing is i am trying to first duplicate data from B3:H101, then paste data from column J3:J under my data in column I, and lastly fill in column A with J2 for all blank cells. I need to repeat this for the other columns as well. For example copy again B3:H101 under last data, copy dat from column K3:K this time, under column I, and lastly fill in column A with what is the title for column K, this is K2.

Comment: I have used your code and have updated my post with the code i have for what i am describing in the comments. Do you know any other way of duplicating rows and bringing columns one under the other ( but their titles should always be filled in respctive lines in column A (making all possible combinations.

Comment: @Mpoumpouki i'm glad this solved your posted question.  for other questions, please create a new post, so that we can have targeted dialogue.  There are many issues that can occur when using multiple macros simultaneously, e.g., calls from another macro without needed input, so getting that in a consolidated place would do wonders.

Comment: @Mpoumpouki as a lead, looking up looping `.Value = .Value` to lastrow+1, so you are constantly appending data to your list.